# Adding .NET 4.0 to installshield 2011

Tags: installation, installshield

I have added Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 Full to my installer, and set it to extract from setup.exe, however when I run the installer its starts to download and then install .Net 4 instead of installing it from the installer directly without downloading.

Does anybody have a clue as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you also need to change one option in Release menu, where you configure setup.exe.
It option calls `InstallShield Prerequisites Location` (can has another, but similar name, I use 2012 version) in `Setup.exe` tab, you need change it either to `Follow Individual Selections` or to `Extract from Setup.exe`.